# CompareValidator does not work with single digit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used below compare validator for comparing 2 textbox value of gridview in ItemTemplate...Problem is that when i enter 2 digit number it not allowing single digit values.,and also allows 3 digit value

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator"
                      runat="server"
                      ErrorMessage="Attended Lectures must be Lesser!"
                      ControlToValidate="tbattendedlectures"
                      ControlToCompare="tbtotalattendence"  
                      Display="Dynamic" 
                      Operator="LessThanEqual" 
                      ValidationGroup="bottom">*</asp:CompareValidator>
```

- If I enter "12" in `tb-1` and 16 in `tb-2` --> `true`
- If I enter "2" in `tb-1` --> `false`
- If I enter "02" in `tb-1` --> `true`

Answer (score 2):

Set [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type.aspx) attribute on your validator to `Integer`:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator" runat="server" Type="Integer"
    (...) />
```

Otherwise values are compared as strings, and that's why you're getting wrong results.